# how to write several rasterStack in a loop with R

Tags: r, loops, stack, ncdf4

I have several ncdf files in a folder. I would like to stack them individually in a loop and print their information in R.

I have the following code:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)

c <- list.files(pattern="nc")
for (i in 1:length(c)){
   ff <- stack(c[i])
   print(ff[i])
}
```

by typing ff[1] in the command line, I expected to get that:

```
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 444, 922, 409368, 10  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.0625, 0.0625  (x, y)
extent      : 235.375, 293, 25.125, 52.875  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10
```

but I get the following:

```
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
[1,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
[1,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
```

I do not see where is my error. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `print(ff[i])`, you want to do `print(ff)`.

`ff` is a `RaxterStack`. `ff[i]` will give you the values of cell `i`.

((If you wanted layer `j`, you can do `ff[[j]]`))

Avoid `c` as a variable name (it is also a function). I would do

```
library(raster)
ff <- list.files(pattern="nc")
for (i in 1:length(ff)) {
   s <- stack(ff[i])
   print(s)
}
```

or better

```
for (i in 1:length(ff)) {
   b <- brick(ff[i])
   print(b)
}
```

or perhaps like this:

```
library(raster)
ff <- list.files(pattern="nc")
lapply(ff, brick)
```

Comment: What I would like is to get access to rasterStack 1, and rasterStack2. I am not looking for accessing the raster layer.

Comment: Yes: use `print(ff)`

Comment: with these lines of code:                                                                                                      for (i in 1:length(ff)) {
      s <- stack(ff[i])
      print(s)
     }
It print all the rasterStack but I do not understand how I can retrieve each individual stack after. For example, I would like to access the rasterStack n*50 in the iteration of the loop.

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying. Perhaps you can edit your question to explain what you want.